# python argparse like --home-path

Tags: python, argparse

I have a question, where I can't find an answer for. This is my codeblock:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', help='just for testing')
parser.add_argument('--home-path', help='specify the homepath')
args = parser.parser_args()
if args.test:
        print('Test')
```

How can I access the '--home-path' argument like the test argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the `-` with `_` in the attribute name:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.home_path:
    # Do stuff
```

This behavior is documented under [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) in [`ArgumentParser.add_argument()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method):

> For optional argument actions, the value of `dest` is normally inferred
>   from the option strings. [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) generates the value of `dest` by
>   taking the first long option string and stripping away the initial `--`
>   string. If no long option strings were supplied, `dest` will be derived
>   from the first short option string by stripping the initial `-`
>   character. Any internal `-` characters will be converted to `_` characters
>   to make sure the string is a valid attribute name.